# Storing data on Firebase to be queried later

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

We have an application that will store data on Firebase (database) that will then be queried later.

What is the correct format to store the data in.

The example data will be completedGames. They will have data such as:
UserId
TimeToComplete
GameData
Etc...

The query later will then look for all completed games by UserId. We want to ensure the data is collected in the best way possible to query later, rather than refactoring later.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, first off - be sure you have a good reason to use Firebase over Firestore. Once you're confident you should stick with Firebase Realtime Database, look at the below excerpt of documentation.  So, you might actually have 2 separate parent nodes, 1 for userId and another for games. Each game node's child is a particular game, which has a child tree of game users  (by userId).

> [Flatten data
>   structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)
>   If the data is instead split into separate paths, also called
>   denormalization, it can be efficiently downloaded in separate calls,
>   as it is needed. Consider this flattened structure:
>
> ```
> {
>   // Chats contains only meta info about each conversation
>   // stored under the chats's unique ID
>   "chats": {
>     "one": {
>       "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
>       "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
>       "timestamp": 1459361875666
>     },
>     "two": { ... },
>     "three": { ... }
>   },
>
>   // Conversation members are easily accessible
>   // and stored by chat conversation ID
>   "members": {
>     // we'll talk about indices like this below
>     "one": {
>       "ghopper": true,
>       "alovelace": true,
>       "eclarke": true
>     },
>     "two": { ... },
>     "three": { ... }
>   },
>
>   // Messages are separate from data we may want to iterate quickly
>   // but still easily paginated and queried, and organized by chat
>   // conversation ID
>   "messages": {
>     "one": {
>       "m1": {
>         "name": "eclarke",
>         "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
>         "timestamp": 1459361875337
>       },
>       "m2": { ... },
>       "m3": { ... }
>     },
>     "two": { ... },
>     "three": { ... }
>   }
> }
> ```